# Bash 'yes a' and 'yes b'

Tags: linux, bash, random, stream, libc

```
bash: $: yes a
[some output] then press Ctrl+Z
      $: yes b
[some output] then press Ctrl+Z
```

then, do bg twice and got some output:

> a b b b a a a a b a a a a b b a b a a a a a b a a a b a a b  a a ... a
>   b b b b b b b b etc.

Why a and b interchange so casually?

Comment: what result do you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do [process scheduling](http://oreilly.com/catalog/linuxkernel/chapter/ch10.html), which is a fairly complex topic.

I don't know enough on the topic to explain precisely why it is random, but it suffices to say that the Linux kernel is deciding how much CPU time each process gets, and based on how many other processes are also running and what exactly they are doing, it can change dramatically.

Comment: I noticed that the  interchange changes when I try to type any character in the console or move my mouse: D

Comment: IIRC things like keyboard and mouse I/O are highest priority, whereas userland processes typically have relatively low priority. E.g., running `yes &>/dev/null &` and viewing it in `top` shows it at priority 20 (the lowest).

Answer (score 0):

Because both processes are running simultaneously?
Isn't that what you would have expected?

Comment: May be, but why not 'ababababababababa'?

Comment: I guess it depends on when each process gets CPU time, and for how long it holds on to it (combined with other things like output buffers, etc)...

Comment: race condition and inaccuracy timer?

Comment: There's no reason (as far as I know) that each process would output just once and give up the cpu.

And then, I guess (this is speculation) the threads _could_ be outputting ababababab, but because the output buffers aren't flushed immediately (are they?) the order might appear differently... maybe...

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, yes doesn't usually give a string all on one line, so I'm assuming that you mean that you want:
a
b
a
b
a
b

I can't think of any shorter way to do that with standard unix commands than this:

`awk 'BEGIN{while (1){print "a\nb"}}'`